# WPF Grid Column resize order

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, resize

is there a way to resize a column of a grid before a other column will be?
So let's assume we have a window of 300px width and 3 columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now I will resize the Window to 600px. Now every column will be 200px in width, but I want them to be 100,400,100. So the second column will be resized to it's max first, before the others will be resized.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks alot

Comment: Do you always want the scale to be 4:1 between the middle and outer columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit "hacky", but this should do the trick:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Edit: Added MinWidth attributes to First and thrid columnDef